# What is the LEGO EV3 rpf file?

Tags: ev3, software

I read the [LEGO Mindstorms EV3 Communication Developer Kit's document](https://le-www-live-s.legocdn.com/sc/media/files/ev3-developer-kit/lego%20mindstorms%20ev3%20communication%20developer%20kit-f691e7ad1e0c28a4cfb0835993d76ae3.pdf?la=en-us).

I have a question in 4.2.1 (Start program “Demo” on EV3 brick) it is mentioned "The file-extension is "rpf" and NOT "rbf", so how can I generate the rpf file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rpf` stands for "rudolph program file" [[source](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3sources/blob/78ebaf5b6f8fe31cc17aa5dce0f8e4916a4fc072/extra/linux-03.20.00.13/arch/arm/mach-davinci/bytecodes.h#L72)] (I believe "Rudolf" is the internal code name for EV3.)

These are the files created using the "Brick Program" utility on the EV3 brick. Once you have created a program on the brick, you can upload the file using the EV3 desktop software. You can find the files in the `BrickProg_Save` folder.

[image: screenshot]

However, after explaining all of that, I think the documentation you linked may be a bit misleading. The file extension does not *have* to be `.rpf`. The file just has to be an EV3 bytecode file, so a `.rbf` file could be used too. They probably just chose that example since the `Demo.rpf` file is installed by default on the EV3.